# How do I understand this default statement in the Redux shopping cart example?

Tags: javascript, redux

Here's the statement:

```
default:
      const { productId } = action
      if (productId) {
        return {
          ...state,
          [productId]: products(state[productId], action)
        }
      }
      return state
```

Source: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/shopping-cart (src/reducers/products/ - line 26)

Here's what I understand so far:

Line 26: If case RECIEVE_PRODUCTS is not met, execute what comes after the double dots.

Line 27: const productId is set equal to action.productId carried over by the addToCart action.

Line 28: If action.productId exists, execute the statement between the curly brackets.

Line 29 & 30: Return the unchanged properties of state.

Line 31: ?

Line 32-34: Otherwise, return state unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[productId]: products(state[productId], action)` is assigning the result of `products(state[productId], action)` to a key with the value of `productId`. 
Its easier to explain with an example:

```js
const a = 'foo';
const b = 'bar';

const obj = {
  [a]: a,
  b: b
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea what does state in the products reducer mean when it's not predefined? Or where does it get state.inventory from?